# Android: How to animation move the View by using a matrix?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

How to move the View with the animation from the current position (translate, rotate & scale) to a new state of the matrix?

Current values (...) ==> animate ==> New values (scale: 1, transX: 20, transY: 700, angle: 0)

I use the following code, the move occurs without animation.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(20, 700);

MyAnimation animation = new MyAnimation(matrix);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
text_object.setAnimation(animation);
```

MyAnimation.java

```
public class MyAnimation extends Animation {
    private Matrix matrix;

    public MyAnimation(Matrix matrix) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        t.getMatrix().set(matrix);
    }
}
```

How to make the animation work?
What alternatives can be used to achieve this objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why go all the trouble to modify the `Matrix` of the `View` to animate it's scale and traslation. Just use `Property Animation`. You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

You can use an `ObjectAnimator` to perform the animation you require.

Comment: Using "view.animate().x(20).y(700).start();" is a calculation relative to the current object, not the screen. How to specify the coordinates in the global coordinate system?

Comment: Yes. This is relative to the view. If you want to use with relative to screen, you can first find the coordinate of the View. Then use this and the relative position to do your animation. You can try this `View.getLocationOnScreen()` or `getLocationInWindow()`

Answer (score 3):

This question helped me, so despite the fact that it is outdated I'll comment in case it might help others.

In order to animate your matrix you need to change it in respect of `interpolatedTime`. What happens is that you continuously set the matrix to the same value each time the animation runs and this is why it's not working.
There are a few ways to manipulate a matrix, i.e

```
Matrix.setRectToRect()
Matrix.setPolyToPoly()
Matrix.setValues()
```

or using the more standard API.

Here's a class I'm using:

```
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class MatrixAnimation extends Animation {
    private PointF scaleStart;
    private PointF scaleEnd;
    private PointF translateStart;
    private PointF translateEnd;
    private boolean animated = true;

    MatrixAnimation(Matrix startMatrix, Matrix endMatrix){
        this(startMatrix, endMatrix, true);
    }

    MatrixAnimation(Matrix startMatrix, Matrix endMatrix, boolean animated){
        float[] a = new float[9];
        float[] b = new float[9];

        startMatrix.getValues(a);
        endMatrix.getValues(b);

        scaleStart = new PointF(a[Matrix.MSCALE_X], a[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
        scaleEnd =  new PointF(b[Matrix.MSCALE_X], b[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
        translateStart = new PointF(a[Matrix.MTRANS_X], a[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
        translateEnd = new PointF(b[Matrix.MTRANS_X], b[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);

        setFillAfter(true);
        //setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    protected MatrixAnimation setAnimated(boolean animated){
        this.animated = animated;
        setDuration(animated ? 300 : 0);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
        PointF sFactor = new PointF(
                scaleEnd.x * interpolatedTime / scaleStart.x + 1 - interpolatedTime,
                scaleEnd.y * interpolatedTime / scaleStart.y + 1 - interpolatedTime);
        PointF tFactor = new PointF(
                (translateEnd.x - translateStart.x) * interpolatedTime,
                (translateEnd.y - translateStart.y) * interpolatedTime);

        //Log.d(TAG, "applyTransformation: " + sFactor + " " + tFactor);

        matrix.postScale(scaleStart.x, scaleStart.y, 0, 0);
        matrix.postScale(sFactor.x, sFactor.y, 0, 0);
        matrix.postTranslate(translateStart.x, translateStart.y);
        matrix.postTranslate(tFactor.x, tFactor.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        setAnimated(true);
        super.start();
    }

    public void start(boolean animated){
        setAnimated(animated);
        super.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! U answer DO help me !

Comment: WOW, This is amazing! Awesome! Thanks for saving my days.

Comment: How to us this? i tried it using class instace but failed

Answer (score 0):

late to the party but what you can do is just create a copy of the initial matrix and the matrix you want to achieve and then use a MatrixEvaluator() for the difference between the 2 and animate it.

the example is from an extansion of ImageView I use

```
private fun animateScaleMatrix(scaleFactor: Float, pivot: PointF){
    var matrixEvaluator = MatrixEvaluator()
    val oldMatrix = Matrix(mCurrentMatrix)
    val scaledMatrix = Matrix(mCurrentMatrix)
    scaledMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor, pivot.x,pivot.y)

    mCurrentScale *= scaleFactor

    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f)
    animator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
        mCurrentMatrix = matrixEvaluator.evaluate(animation.animatedFraction, oldMatrix, scaledMatrix)
        invalidate()
    }
    animator.setDuration(300)
    animator.start()
}
```